# Crate dictionary with for in in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary with looping using for in swift

but the result that appears is only the last value

my code is

```
  let items = [10, 9, 8 , 7, 6]
    
  var paramp: [String: Any] = [:]
  for item in items {
        paramp["paramp_id"] = item
  }
```

the resulst is **["paramp_id" : 6]**

the results i want is

```
["paramp_id" : 10]
["paramp_id" : 9]
["paramp_id" : 8]
["paramp_id" : 7]
["paramp_id" : 6]
```

i want to get all the dictionary

Comment: Of course you are overwriting the key value every iteration. You need one key for each value

Comment: The result that appears is the result you asked for in your code. What result did you _want?_ From your code, it's impossible to guess. What did you want the keys to be?

Comment: i want all dictionary with the items value

Comment: Maybe you actually want an array of dictionaries (I'm not sure why one would want this): `[["paramp_id" : 10],["paramp_id" : 9],etc]`

Comment: The result you want does not make sense. A dictionary can only contain one entry for a given key. You need to explain what you are trying to do with your data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing an array of single-value dictionaries. That's unlikely to be useful. What you really want is probably an array of *structs* that have a `paramp_id` property:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let paramp_id: Int
}
let items = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
let structs = items.map {MyStruct(paramp_id:$0)}
```

Comment: Also try to avoid the use of Any.

Comment: or simply `items.map(MyStruct.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Too clever. :)